# How to modify CSS3 scrollbox animation to loop infinitely rather than starting over?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-animations

jsfiddle here because this is way easier to show than to describe: https://jsfiddle.net/phzakg62/

This is a 15-second CSS-only vertical scrolling text animation that, at the end of the 15 seconds, kind of scrolls back up to the top in reverse in order to start over again. (In the real page I am building, it's in a fixed-height box with overflow: hidden, but I removed from the jsfiddle all code that wasn't directly related to the animation.)

Is there a way I can modify this to give the appearance of scrolling forever, without ever starting over again, by having the last LI in the scrolling UL be followed by the first LI? Maybe some kind of dynamic thing that duplicates the UL & appends it to itself at the end of the animation?

I don't imagine there's a CSS-only solution here so I added the JavaScript tag to this question, but I'd love it if there were something that didn't break the CSS-only animation for people whose JS is turned off.

Thanks in advance.

```
#scroll-wrap ul {
  animation: scroller 15s cubic-bezier(1, 0, .5, 0) infinite;
}

@keyframes scroller {
    0%   {margin-top: 0}
    5%   {margin-top: -5.12rem}
    10%  {margin-top: -10.24rem}
    15%  {margin-top: -15.36rem}
    20%  {margin-top: -20.48rem}
    25%  {margin-top: -25.6rem}
    30%  {margin-top: -30.72rem}
    35%  {margin-top: -35.84rem}
    40%  {margin-top: -41rem}
    45%  {margin-top: -46.12rem}
    50%  {margin-top: -51.24rem}
    55%  {margin-top: -56.36rem}
    60%  {margin-top: -61.48rem}
    65%  {margin-top: -66.6rem}
    70%  {margin-top: -71.72rem}
    75%  {margin-top: -76.84rem}
    80%  {margin-top: -82rem}
    85%  {margin-top: -87.12rem}
    90%  {margin-top: -92.24rem}
    95%  {margin-top: -97.36rem}
    100% {margin-top: 0}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be done in CSS only by duplicating the list in the html.

I just put the same list twice (you would have to slow down the animation by half). And at the last frame quickly scroll back to the top.

It's not a very nice solution but it is CSS only.

```
<div id="scroll-wrap">
    <ul id="scroller">

       ...items...

       ...exact copy of items...
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#scroll-wrap ul {
    animation: scroller 15s cubic-bezier(1, 0, .5, 0) infinite;
}

@keyframes scroller {
    0%   {margin-top: 0}
    ...
    50%  {margin-top: -25rem}
    90%  {margin-top: -45rem}
    95%  {margin-top: -49rm}
    99.9% {margin-top: -50rem}
    100% {margin-top: 0}
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/phzakg62/4/

Comment: Thanks, Bob. In the real page, both the list and the animation are considerably longer than what I have here, so that's definitely the plan if I can't come up with a way to eliminate the scroll-back-to-top action entirely.

Comment: I forgot to add that you should only scroll to 50% percent in my jsfiddle. That will give the illusion of an infinite scroll.

Answer (score 0):

The scrolling might be problematic. Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/phzakg62/6/

```
var add_counter = 0
var original_length = $('#scroller li').size()

setInterval(function () {
    $('#scroller').append($('#scroller li:nth-child(' + add_counter % original_length + ')').clone())
    $('#scroller').css('margin-top', -add_counter * $('#scroller li:first-child').height())
    add_counter++
}, 200)
```

Comment: I appreciate this but the scrolling effect is too different from what I was after. Thanks.